# Five-level iteration loop in ansible for netbox

Tags: ansible, netbox

First of all thank for reading my post. I am a neewbie in Ansible and have this devices.yml file

```
devices:
  test-device1:
    name: Test Device 1
    device_type: test-device-type1
    device_role: router1
    site: UoP
    position: 12
    rack: Lande
    face: Front
    serial: "864kjfhi3y74"
    # primary_ip4: ""
    # description: ""
    # commments: ""
    interfaces:
      - name: GigabitEthernet22
        enabled: true
        mgmt_only: false
        type: 1000Base-t (1GE)
        mode: Access
        untagged_vlan: vlan401
      - name: GigabitEthernet23
        enabled: false
        mgmt_only: false
        type: 1000Base-t (1GE)
        mode: Tagged
        untagged_vlan: vlan401
        tagged_vlans: 
          - vlan1000
          - vlan1015
        lag:
          name: port-channel1
 

  test-device2:
    name: Test Device 2
    device_type: test-device-type2
    device_role: switch1
    site: UoP
    position: 14
    rack: Lande
    face: Front
    # serial: 
    # primary_ip4: 10.1.3.192
    description: Test device 2
    comments: Test
    interfaces:
      - name: ether20
        ip4: 10.1.3.192
        enabled: true
        mgmt_only: true
        type: 1000Base-t (1GE)
        mode: Tagged
        untagged_vlan: vlan401
        tagged_vlans: 
          - vlan1014
        lag:
          name: port-channel1
```

and am trying to access the tagged_vlans list required from the netbox module (description [here](https://netbox-ansible-collection.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins/netbox_device_interface_module.html#ansible-collections-netbox-netbox-netbox-device-interface-module)

using the following task:

```
- name: Create interfaces
  netbox.netbox.netbox_device_interface:
    data:
      device: "{{ item.value.name }}"
      name: "{{ item.value.interfaces.0.name }}"
      enabled: "{{ item.value.interfaces.0.enabled }}"
      type: "{{ item.value.interfaces.0.type|default(omit) }}"
      untagged_vlan:
        name: "{{ item.value.interfaces.0.untagged_vlan|default(omit) }}"
      tagged_vlans:
        name: "{{ item.value.interfaces.0.tagged_vlans.0|default(omit) }}"
        site: "{{ item.value.site }}"
      mgmt_only: "{{ item.value.interfaces.0.mgmt_only|default(omit) }}"
      mode: "{{ item.value.interfaces.0.mode|default(omit) }}"
    state: present
  loop: "{{ devices | dict2items }}"
```

I am expecting the loop to run for each vlan ID described in the tagged_vlans list. See here the error I am getting

> ..... The request failed with code 400 Bad Request: {'tagged_vlans': ['**Expected a list of items but got type "int"**.']}\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}

I think I am providing the list, so what is the problem here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Nikos Kallergis found the answer which is change the datastructure of the tagged_vlans from

```
tagged_vlans:
  - vlan1000
  - vlan1015
```

to

```
tagged_vlans:
  - name: vlan1000
  - name: vlan1015
```

and change the task from

```
 tagged_vlans:
   name: "{{ item.1.tagged_vlans.0|default(omit) }}"
```

to

```
 tagged_vlans: "{{ item.1.tagged_vlans.0|default(omit) }}"
```

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

Iterate with subelements

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          device: "{{ item.0.value.name }}"
          name: "{{ item.1.name }}"
          enabled: "{{ item.1.enabled }}"
          type: "{{ item.1.type|default(omit) }}"
          untagged_vlan:
            name: "{{ item.1.untagged_vlan|default(omit) }}"
          tagged_vlans:
            name: "{{ item.1.tagged_vlans.0|default(omit) }}"
            site: "{{ item.0.value.site }}"
          mgmt_only: "{{ item.1.mgmt_only|default(omit) }}"
          mode: "{{ item.1.mode|default(omit) }}"
      loop: "{{ devices|dict2items|subelements('value.interfaces') }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.0.key }}: {{ item.1.name }}"
```

gives (running on localhost)

```yaml
TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=test-device1: GigabitEthernet22) => 
  msg: |-
    device: "Test Device 1"
    name: "GigabitEthernet22"
    enabled: "True"
    type: "1000Base-t (1GE)"
    untagged_vlan:
      name: "vlan401"
    tagged_vlans:
      name: "__omit_place_holder__2ab16b4ae48a136687850c661f480ce08c86fd93"
      site: "UoP"
    mgmt_only: "False"
    mode: "Access"
ok: [localhost] => (item=test-device1: GigabitEthernet23) => 
  msg: |-
    device: "Test Device 1"
    name: "GigabitEthernet23"
    enabled: "False"
    type: "1000Base-t (1GE)"
    untagged_vlan:
      name: "vlan401"
    tagged_vlans:
      name: "vlan1000"
      site: "UoP"
    mgmt_only: "False"
    mode: "Tagged"
ok: [localhost] => (item=test-device2: ether20) => 
  msg: |-
    device: "Test Device 2"
    name: "ether20"
    enabled: "True"
    type: "1000Base-t (1GE)"
    untagged_vlan:
      name: "vlan401"
    tagged_vlans:
      name: "vlan1014"
      site: "UoP"
    mgmt_only: "True"
    mode: "Tagged"
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    devices:
      test-device1:
        name: Test Device 1
        device_type: test-device-type1
        device_role: router1
        site: UoP
        position: 12
        rack: Lande
        face: Front
        serial: "864kjfhi3y74"
        # primary_ip4: ""
        # description: ""
        # commments: ""
        interfaces:
          - name: GigabitEthernet22
            enabled: true
            mgmt_only: false
            type: 1000Base-t (1GE)
            mode: Access
            untagged_vlan: vlan401
          - name: GigabitEthernet23
            enabled: false
            mgmt_only: false
            type: 1000Base-t (1GE)
            mode: Tagged
            untagged_vlan: vlan401
            tagged_vlans: 
              - vlan1000
              - vlan1015
            lag:
              name: port-channel1
      test-device2:
        name: Test Device 2
        device_type: test-device-type2
        device_role: switch1
        site: UoP
        position: 14
        rack: Lande
        face: Front
        # serial: 
        # primary_ip4: 10.1.3.192
        description: Test device 2
        comments: Test
        interfaces:
          - name: ether20
            ip4: 10.1.3.192
            enabled: true
            mgmt_only: true
            type: 1000Base-t (1GE)
            mode: Tagged
            untagged_vlan: vlan401
            tagged_vlans: 
              - vlan1014
            lag:
              name: port-channel1

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: |
          device: "{{ item.0.value.name }}"
          name: "{{ item.1.name }}"
          enabled: "{{ item.1.enabled }}"
          type: "{{ item.1.type|default(omit) }}"
          untagged_vlan:
            name: "{{ item.1.untagged_vlan|default(omit) }}"
          tagged_vlans:
            name: "{{ item.1.tagged_vlans.0|default(omit) }}"
            site: "{{ item.0.value.site }}"
          mgmt_only: "{{ item.1.mgmt_only|default(omit) }}"
          mode: "{{ item.1.mode|default(omit) }}"
      loop: "{{ devices|dict2items|subelements('value.interfaces') }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.0.key }}: {{ item.1.name }}"
```